# How to full screen command prompt in a Virtualbox XP vm?

Tags: windows-xp, command-line, virtualbox

I am running a legacy DOS application in windows XP command prompt and I can't manage to show it full screen. As I saw, this is not only my DOS app, but every command prompt I open in Windows vbox, which appears in the center of the window with a very small font.

I've played around with the window properties, but nothing seems to fix this and I definitely need to have this working in full screen. Please keep in mind that in a Windows XP machine (not a vbox but a physical one) it works fine.

[image: xp_command]

Comment: why downvote ? At least say something...

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see, this command prompt window is already full screen, that's just how large your VM screen is.
To make it bigger, you can install VirtualBox guest addition(on the VM) so that the VM screen scales to the size of the VirtualBox window.  You should find the "install guest addition" item by searching the VirtualBox Menu.
I've never used VirtualBox on Mac before, so not sure if it works same way there but you can try it. 
[image]

Comment: I've already done this. Windows environment scales successfully and only command prompt appears like that.

Comment: Then I have no idea. I'm sorry.

Comment: If you are on a Real PC running XP, and you full screen cmd, the screen resolution will lower to 720x440 or something, that's a fact. So truth is, full screen cmd cannot take advantage of the big screen, so in virtualbox, it becomes this.

Comment: you can try scale mode.